# Static File in HTML gets distorted when implemented in pythonanywhere server

Tags: html, django, offline, pythonanywhere

Hello my question is about why the formatting language of my static file resource gets twisted when rendering. The thing that gets affected the most is spanish special characters like: 'ó' or 'ñ'.

For instance: Indicadores de Gestión para Ciudad de México en el Mes de Noviembre 2017.

Gets rendered like this: Indicadores de GestiÃ³n para Ciudad de MÃ©xico en el Mes de Noviembre 2017.

I am using Django 1.11 and my app is hosted in pythonanywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the character set of your files, encoding them `in utf-8`, for example [for css files](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset). Most text editors let you convert the files to utf-8.

As mentioned there:

> Note! It is not enough to simply put @charset "utf-8"; at the top of
>   the style sheet – you need to also save your style sheet in the UTF-8
>   character encoding. (See Applying an encoding to your content.)

In python files you declare at the top of the files

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

In html files you declare in meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that when I try to modify my file as it is static and not a template. Django does not pass the new values. By any chance you know how to reload specific changes. (Shift does not gets the job done). And I am using a service worker so the file is saved inside the cache.

Comment: @SantiagoM.Quintero I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Is it related to the post? You can't change the files? I don't know what 'Shift' is.

Comment: Thank you the problem radicated on the fact that the file was served throug a manifest.